# MYSQL - Order column by ASCII Value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, ascii

I have a column with texts, sorted by ASCII it should be ordered as:

```
-  (hyphen)
0
1  (numbers)
2
A  (uppercase)
B
_  (underscore)
a
b  (lowercase)
c
```

However it is being ordered as:

```
-  (hyphen)
0
1  (numbers)
2
a
b  (lowercase)
c
A
B  (uppercase)
C
_  (underscore)
```

How can I do the sorting by ASCII value?

Comment: Simply use functions to convert all values to upper/lower for sorting purposes? them all to upper/lower.... `order by Upper(column)`  or `order by lower(column) `

Comment: That doesnt work, because you'll end up with lower and upercase elements mixed up.

Comment: Very true, I missread the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sort order is controlled by the collation. You can use the BINARY collation to sort by raw bytes, which in the case of ASCII data will cause it to sort by ASCII value. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

```
SELECT ...
FROM mytable
ORDER BY BINARY mycolumn
```

This will be more flexible than using the `ASCII()` function because that function only returns the ASCII value of the first character. Using the BINARY collation allows sorting by the full string.

Comment: This is what i wanted!

Answer (score 6):

You could use [ASCII](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY ASCII(col_name) ASC
```

Comment: This only works for the first character.

If i has  Ab and Ac they wouldn't be sorted correctly.